# Unable to install mesa-common-dev:i386 on my ubuntu system

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, mesa

I am using Ubuntu(12.04 LTS) x86_64 GNU/Linux. I have to setup my build environment on my Ubuntu system. While trying to instal the `mesa-common-dev:i386` package, I am facing the following error.

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev:i386

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mesa-common-dev-lts-quantal : Conflicts: mesa-common-dev:i386
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Please suggest ways to get rid of this.

Comment: I need to install mesa-comon-dev:i386 32 bit package for building the code. Can't I remove the mesa-common-dev-lts-quantal and install the mesa-comon-dev:i386 package. Because I am getting the below build error while compiling the code.

 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You can remove the -lts version of course to compile 32bit packages, it will allow the mesa-comon-dev:i386 package to install without any conflicts

Answer (score 0):

You already have `mesa-common-dev` properly installed on your system via `mesa-common-dev-lts-quantal` which is a backport of the 12.10 version (9.0.3) where Ubuntu 12.04 only provides 8.0.4.

So both are not co-installable hence the conflicts at packaging level. Moreover you're trying to install a i386 package on a 64bits system.

In term of dependencies, `mesa-common-dev` is correctly installed, there's no need to install additional packages to set up your build environment.